# MS Access SQL SELECTing the MAX from grouped data

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I have a dataset containing 3 columns ( CustomerID, ProductCode, LastDate) with no duplicates.
LastDate is the date of last purchase of the product by that Customer.

I need to extract only rows showing the max(LastDate) for a given CustomerID/ProductCode.
That is, I need to know which Customer most recently purchased a product.

Any help with the SQL would be appreciated.
James

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your data seems to already answer the question "which Customer most recently purchased a product".

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

It firsts gets the last purchase date for a product then joins this to the original dataset based on the product code and last date to retrieve the customer who purchased the product last.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    dataset.CustomerId,
    dataset.ProductCode,
    dataset.LastDate
FROM
    dataset 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
    ProductCode,
    MAX(LastDate) LastDate
FROM
    dataset
GROUP BY
    ProductCode
) last_purchased ON dataset.ProductCode = last_purchased.ProductCode AND
                    dataset.LastDate = last_purchased.LastDate
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi ggordon, thanks for your prompt reply and suggestions which are close to what I want.
However, I don't feel I was clear enough in my question so I have posted a new question at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249205/ms-access-sql-extracting-a-dataset-of-latest-dates-from-grouped-data

Answer (score 0):

Use *DMax* for one value:

```vb
CustomerID = TheCustomerIDToFind    ' Number
ProductCode = TheProductCodeToFind  ' Text

LastDate = DMax("LastDate", "YourTable", "CustomerID = " & CustomerID & " And ProductCode = '" & ProductCode & "'"
```

or for many:

```sql
Select CustomerID, ProductCode, Max(LastDate)
From YourTable
Group By CustomerID, ProductCode
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for your prompt reply and suggestions
I wasn't clear enough in my question so I have posted a new question at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249205/ms-access-sql-extracting-a-dataset-of-latest-dates-from-grouped-data