# MS Access SQL extracting a dataset of latest dates from grouped data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following 3 tables: The first holds actual purchases by Customers, the second is price quotes to a customer for a product
and the third shows any interest (Sale or quote) in a product by a customer.

[image]

A customer may simply purchase a product, or get a quote and never purchase, or get a quote and then later purchase a product.

I need to extract a dataset that shows the most recent date that a product was either sold or quoted to a customer.
So, sorted by ProductCode, I want a dataset that looks like this ...

[image]

I could do this in SQLServer but can't quite get what I want in MSAccess SQL.
Any help with the MSAccess SQL would be appreciated. James

Comment: How do you do it in SQL Server?

Comment: Table 3 appears to be duplication of data found in the first two tables and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First build a UNION query of Orders and Quotes:

```
SELECT [Date], CustomerID, ProductCode, "Order" AS Cat FROM SalesOrders
UNION SELECT [Date], CustomerID, ProductCode, "Quote" FROM Quotes;
```

Use that query in another query to return TOP 1 record for each product:

```
SELECT * FROM OrdersQuotesUNION
WHERE [CustomerID] & [Cat] & [Date] In (
    SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID & Cat & [Date] FROM OrdersQuotesUNION AS Dup 
    WHERE Dup.ProductCode = OrdersQuotesUNION.ProductCode ORDER BY Date DESC)
ORDER BY OrdersQuotesUNION.ProductCode;
```

Comment: Thanks June 7. I developed something similar to this. So I have marked this as the answer.
Btw table 3 has other fields not shown for simplicity.